# Is it possible to scroll and stick as a header when it reaches the top of screen in android?

Tags: android, header, scroll

I am looking for a technique to create a scrollable list that is divided into sections. Each section has section name on the top of the list. When users scroll down (move gesture upwardly), the section name reaches the top of screen and sticks on the top of screen view until its section items disappear from the screen. Is it possible? if so, is there any examples source code available?

Thanks in advance.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the answer to your question:

https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyScrollViewItems